# Can't load model in controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, undefined

Since a couple of days I can't load a model in a codeigniter system anymore.

It gives the following error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Clients::$mdl_clients

Filename: controllers/clients.php

Line Number: 48
```

Controller code:

```
private function GetAllClients()
    {
        $this->load->model('clients_model', 'mdl_clients');

        $clients = $this->mdl_clients->getClients()->result_array();
        return $clients;
    }
```

I read the codeigniter documentation again, and I'am not doing anything wrong that I'am aware of..
Can you guys help me out?

Comment: Has your OS or PHP version changed?

Comment: No, same server and php has not been updated..

Comment: Assuming that it's not a typo, just double check that all you classes have the same name as their file (case sensitive). Make sure they both start with a capital letter and the rest are lower case. If the class has `MY_` the my should be capitalised and the first letter after it...again make sure your file names match the class declaration e.g. `MY_Form_validation.php` `class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation`.

Comment: Looking at the error its is not treating the `mdl_clients` as a model, but part of the `client class`. Maybe your controller is extending a wrong controller or not extending at all, or you have an object which has a name of `mdl_clients` lying around somewhere.

Comment: Cay you show us model name in path ?

Comment: @RossWilson I just double checked every class and model name.. No typo's here

Comment: @tomexsans No indeed, thats what my first thought was. But changed the mdl_clients to something else, and still no luck. I checked the Clients controller and it is extending just the right controller (MY_Controller) like it always did..

Comment: You model isn't using PHP 4 style constructor is it? And are you using an HMVC pattern?

Comment: It was a weird issue with my server. I uploaded everything to another, and it works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a weird issue with my server. I uploaded everything to another, and it worked again

Answer (score 0):

Change the model name by 'clients_model.php' if you dont have, and your class most name 'Clients_model'